# Mondrian rolap schema upgrader

Tags: java, mondrian, saiku

I have mondrian xml schema (3 version). When I'm using my schema(v3) in mondrian 4 - it automatically trying to convert my schema throught `RolapSchemaUpgrader`. But during convertation it throws exception:

```
16:21:20,816 WARN  [RolapSchema] Model is in legacy format
16:21:36,059 ERROR [SecurityAwareConnectionManager] Error connecting: cubetl
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchema$PhysLink.deriveSql(RolapSchema.java:2046)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchema$PhysLink.<init>(RolapSchema.java:2004)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchema$PhysSchema.addLink(RolapSchema.java:945)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchemaUpgrader.registerRelation(RolapSchemaUpgrader.java:3013)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapSchemaUpgrader.convertHierarchy(RolapSchemaUpgrader.java:2800)
```

I haven't any ideas why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. In my case I had to add `primaryKey` attribute for each `Hierarchy`. Documentation told us:

> If not specified, the key of the lowest level is used.

but it didn't work for me.